# preg_replace in PHP

Tags: php, zen-cart

```
$content = preg_replace('%^\s*<ul>(.+)</ul>\s*$%sim', '\1', $menulist);
```

What is the meaning of first argument in the above function?

If I print $content I get the following categories as below:

## Business

### Accounting

#### Accounting For Leasing

#### Acqusition Disposition

#### Balance Sheet And Cash Flows

```
and so on....
```

Now Business is main category and Accounting is its subcategoy. Now I want to store them in array. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

from above:

The **pattern** to search for. It can be either a string or an array with strings.

Comment: I'm not able to understand the argument in given function. $menulist is the array of words.

Comment: The first argument is a regular expression (WHAT you want to search inside the array of strings $menulist), the second one is what you will replace when a pattern will be found, the third one is the subject (string or array of strings where to serach/replace)

Comment: you should explode (http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the $content ;) ..i.e. $myArrayOfCategories = explode(' ',$content)

Comment: If i print using "htmlspecialchars" then I see the following output: <ul class="bullet-menu" id="siteMenu"> <li><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/business">Business</a> <ul> <li><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/business/accounting">Accounting</a> <ul> <li><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/business/accounting/accounting-for-leasing">Accounting For Leasing</a></li> <li><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/business/accounting/acqusition-disposition">Acqusition Disposition</a></li>  .... How can i use explode now ?

Answer (score 0):

The first argument is regular expression, it's a sort of language for string matching. It's widely used in the programming world and supported by most languages like PHP, JavaScript, Python and many more. You can find out more about regular expression here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression and read up one the function `preg_replace()` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: You totally changed your question, you asked what the first argument for `preg_replace()` was and an explanation for it. Now you asking something totally else.

Answer (score 0):

It Performs a regular expression search against a content and replace the matched string with the given replace string.

```
<?php
$string = 'April 15, 2003';
$pattern = '/(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)/i';
$replacement = '${1}1,$3';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>

The above example will output:

April1,2003
```

Read more about this on http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: If I print $content I get the following categories as below: Business
  Accounting
    Accounting For Leasing
    Acqusition Disposition
    Balance Sheet And Cash Flows
    and so on....